# PHP simplexml search

Tags: php, search, simplexml

I have the following XML file loaded into a php simplexml variable and I need to find the status and unit_id from one of the bin children. I will already know which `shelve[]` child it will be under just not the bin child.

```
<frames>
    <shelve>
        <bins>
            <bin>
                <bin_id>3</bin_id>
                <status>OPEN</status>
            </bin>
            <bin>
                <bin_id>2</bin_id>
                <status>OPEN</status>
            </bin>
        </bins>
    </shelve>
    <shelve>
        <bins>
            <bin>
                <units>
                    <unit>
                        <unit_id>123456789</id>
                    </unit>
                </units>
                <bin_id>1</bin_id>
                <status>TAKEN</status>
            </bin>
            <bin>
                <bin_id>2</bin_id>
                <status>OPEN</status>
            </bin>
        </bins>
    </shelve>
</frames>
```

for example I need to get the status and the `unit_id` where `bin_id = 1`. So how would I go about finding the path to the correct `bin[]`?

```
frames->shelve[1]->bins->bin[0]->status

frames->shelve[1]->bins->bin[0]->units->unit->unit_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xpath to query data from an XML. SimpleXml supports it trough its xpath() method, but not completely. DOMXpath::evaluate() is more powerful:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<frames>
    <shelve>
        <bins>
            <bin><bin_id>3</bin_id><status>OPEN</status></bin>
            <bin><bin_id>2</bin_id><status>OPEN</status></bin>
        </bins>
    </shelve>
    <shelve>
        <bins>
            <bin>
                <units><unit><unit_id>123456789</unit_id></unit></units>
                <bin_id>1</bin_id>
                <status>TAKEN</status>
            </bin>
            <bin><bin_id>2</bin_id><status>OPEN</status></bin>
        </bins>
    </shelve>
</frames>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

if ($xpath->evaluate('count(//bin[bin_id = 1])') > 0) {
  $binNode = $xpath->evaluate('//bin[bin_id = 1]')->item(0);
  $unitId = $xpath->evaluate('string(./units/unit/unit_id)', $binNode);
  $status = $xpath->evaluate('string(./status)', $binNode);

  var_dump(
    $unitId, $status
  );
}
```

Output:

```
string(9) "123456789"
string(5) "TAKEN"
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help me a lot. time to do some more reading on xpath